# Assigning $scope variable to ng-model with count

Tags: angularjs, count

I am using AngularJS. I am generating pipeline-like structure. At first `onload` I am having one default `ng-repeat` value. After clicking "add more" I am displaying another list. It goes on adding as long as I am clicking the "add" button.

Now for every new pipeline created I want to assign different names like pipeline1, pipeline2 etc. I am using count to generate random numbers from 1.

Here is my HTML:

Add button

```
    <button data-ng-click="count=count+1;addNew();addCount(count)" data-ng-
    init="count=0">Add New Workboard</button>
```

New pipeline will be created with Pipeline Names.

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" data-ng-
    show="listOfLists.length > 0">
    <div data-ng-repeat="list in listOfLists">
    <ul class="simpleDemo row">
    <li data-ng-repeat="workboard in list">
    {{workboard.Name}} 
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div> 
    <div style="width: 65%; float: left; height: auto;">
    <p class="weak">Workboard Pipeline Name:</p>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input data-ng-model="pipelineName">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Controller.js

```
    $scope.listOfLists = [];
    $scope.workboardStagesWithDefault = [
    {
    Name:"Test"
    },
    {
    Name:"Test2"
    },
    {
    Name:"Test3"
    }
    ];

    $scope.addNew = function(){
       var clonedList = angular.copy($scope.workboardStagesWithDefault);
       $scope.listOfLists.push(clonedList);
    };
     $scope.addCount = function (count) {
         console.log(count);
         $scope.pipelineName = 'Pipeline'+count;
     };
```

Here after clicking the add button I am getting same pipeline names because I am doing the binding. If I click the add button twice, it is showing pipeline 2 for both pipelines. How to assign different pipeline names that count values with the pipeline string?

Comment: Please provide your ng-repeat code here.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, You can do this inside `ng-repeat`, instead of making a function `addCount()`.

**See the below code:**

Here I added `Workboard Pipeline Name: Pipeline {{$index+1}}` inside `ng-repeat`. Which will display Workboard Pipeline Name like Pipeline 2, Pipeline 1 etc..

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" data-ng show="listOfLists.length > 0">
    <div data-ng-repeat="list in listOfLists track by $index">   
     Workboard Pipeline Name: Pipeline {{$index+1}}       
      <ul class="simpleDemo row">
        <li data-ng-repeat="workboard in list">
         {{workboard.Name}} 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Please see I have edited my answer. You just need to do {{$index+1}}. If it is helpful then please mark it right and do up. :)

Comment: Yeah helpful.Thank you.

Comment: Pleasure :) Keep Asking..!!

Comment: Is it possible to pass this $index value to add button.This add button is outside ng-repeat scope

Comment: How can i edit the pipeline names.Can i get pipeline names based on index.I have edit icon for every pipeline.If i click it will display pipeline name.Now it is displaying same pipeline names for all pipelines instead of selected pipeline pipelineName?

Comment: @SachinHR, Can you please post a new question with the current code? And in that question, explain in detail what you want. And post your question link in the comment here so that I can also see it.

Comment: Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404126/ng-model-taking-for-all-inputs-after-clicking-edit