# ng-model taking for all inputs after clicking edit

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS. I am generating pipeline-like structure. At first `onload` I am having one default `ng-repeat` value. After clicking "add more" I am displaying another list. It goes on adding as long as I am clicking the "add" button.

Here is my HTML:

Add button

```
    <button data-ng-click="addNew()">Add New Workboard</button>
```

New pipeline will be created with Pipeline Names and one text box to add stageNames

```
    <div data-ng-show="listOfLists.length > 0">
    <div data-ng-repeat="list in listOfLists"> 
    <div data-ng-repeat="pipeline in workboardstages track by $index">
    <div class="added-eachboard">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input name="pipelineName" id="pipelineName" data-ng-
    model="pipeline.pipelineName"  type="text">
    </div>
    <ul class="simpleDemo workboard-drags" data-ng-repeat="(key,
    workboardlist) in pipeline.workBoardStageMap">
    <li data-ng-if="pipeline.pipelineName == key" ng-repeat="workboard in
    workboardlist">{{workboard.stageName}} 
    <a href ="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-
    click="editWorkboardStage(workboard.stageId)"><img src = 
    "resources/zingy/images/Edit-Small.png" class="TableIcon"></a> 
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
    <p class="weak">Stage Name:</p>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input name="stageName" id="stageName" data-ng-
    model="newworkboard.stageName"  type="text">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>            
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Controller.js

```
    $scope.listOfLists = [];
    $scope.workboardStagesWithDefault = [
    {
    Name:"Test"
    },
    {
    Name:"Test2"
    },
    {
    Name:"Test3"
    }
    ];

    $scope.addNew = function(){
       var clonedList = angular.copy($scope.workboardStagesWithDefault);
       $scope.listOfLists.push(clonedList);
    };

    $scope.editWorkboardStage = function(stageId){
    AccountService.editWorkboardStage(stageId).then(function(response){
        $scope.newworkboard = response.data;
    });
    }

    $scope.getAllWorkboardStages = function(){
    AccountService.getAllWorkboardStages().then(function(response){
        $scope.workboardstages = response.data;
         $scope.listOfLists.push($scope.workboardstages);
    });
    }
```

After clicking edit i am displaying stage name in that particular text box.But the problem is it is displaying same for neighbouring pipeline also.I want to display only for that current pipeline.As i am displaying using ng-model it is taking for all pipelines.How to display the value only for that particular pipeline?

Comment: If you wana get the details of the current pipeline only then use ngrepeat in select for that section only

Comment: Can u brief a bit.I didnt get

Comment: You have given data-ng-repeat="pipeline in workboardstages track by $index" in a div that creates a value change by index in complete div and two ul with an ng repeat that creates a loop which takes two simutaneous values .

Comment: @SachinHR, Your newworkboard.stageName is based on what? list wise or pipeline wise?

Comment: It is based on stage id.I am getting stage name based on stage Id.Every pipeline has one id.Inside newworkboard object i have stageName,stageId,pipelineId properties

Comment: @SachinHR, Please find the answer. If any confusion, do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is related to indexing. I made `$scope.newworkboard` index wise.

**This is the solution:** (newworkboard is based on pipeline index and pass index from `editWorkboardStage` function.)

```
<input name="stageName" id="stageName" data-ng-model="newworkboard[$index].stageName" type="text">
```

AND

```
 <a href ="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="editWorkboardStage(workboard.stageId, $parent.$parent.$index)"><img src = 
"resources/zingy/images/Edit-Small.png" class="TableIcon"></a>
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-show="listOfLists.length > 0">
  <div data-ng-repeat="list in listOfLists"> 
    <div data-ng-repeat="pipeline in workboardstages track by $index">
      <div class="added-eachboard">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="pipelineName" id="pipelineName" data-ng-
          model="pipeline.pipelineName"  type="text">
        </div>
        <ul class="simpleDemo workboard-drags" data-ng-repeat="(key,
        workboardlist) in pipeline.workBoardStageMap">
        <li data-ng-if="pipeline.pipelineName == key" ng-repeat="workboard in
        workboardlist">{{workboard.stageName}} 
        <a href ="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-
        click="editWorkboardStage(workboard.stageId, $parent.$parent.$index)"><img src = 
        "resources/zingy/images/Edit-Small.png" class="TableIcon"></a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <p class="weak">Stage Name:</p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input name="stageName" id="stageName" data-ng-
        model="newworkboard[$index].stageName" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>            
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

In the controller make an array of `newworkboard` and assign `response.data` index wise.

```
$scope.newworkboard = [];
$scope.editWorkboardStage = function(stageId, index){
AccountService.editWorkboardStage(stageId).then(function(response){
    $scope.newworkboard[index] = response.data;
});
```

Comment: yes, i have updated my answer. $index should be index.

Comment: Have you assigned your array => $scope.newworkboard = [];

Comment: Now if i click edit actually it is not coming for that particular pipeline,randomly it is displaying stageNames.If i select 1st stageName then only it is displaying for particular pipeline.If i select second it is displaying in next pipeline.If i select 3rd stageName for 1st pipeline then it is displaying in third pipeline.

Comment: If i select 1st stagename of 1st pipeline then it displays in 1st.If i select 2nd stageName of 1st pipeline then it displays in 2nd pipeline.If i select 3rd stagename of 1st pipeline then it displays in 3rd pipeline.It goes on.Same happens for all pipelines.

Comment: @SachinHR, actually I am not able to understand the problem. Please make it more descriptive.

Comment: Consider i have 3 stagenames in 1st pipeline.And total i have three pipelines.Now if i click 2nd stagename in 1st pipeline it is displaying in 2nd pipeline instead of 1st pipeline.If i click 3rd stagename in first pipeline it is displaying in 3rd pipeline instead of 1st pipeline.It happens for all pipelines.

Comment: If i click 1st stagename in 2nd pipeline it displays in 1st pipeline instead of 2nd pipeline

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am passing $parent.$parent.$index which is your pipeline index. Please see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167275/discussion-between-surjeet-bhadauriya-and-sachin-hr).

Comment: I have posted screenshot.Can you check

Comment: Thank you bro for amazing help